# .append() method doesn't works with &nbsp; in <span>

Tags: jquery, html, string, whitespace

Have following code:

```
$("[id$='somelement_detection']").parent().parent().append("<span id='checkspan_button' class='checkspan checkspan_unchecked'/>&nbsp;</span>");
```

but it produces wrong output:

```
<span class="checkspan checkspan_unchecked" id="checkspan_button"></span>
```

Without `&nbsp;` I can't use this span in IE for some actions. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: did you need a space between the open and end tag..?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the `span` tag incorrectly. Try without `<span/>`

```
$("[id$='somelement_detection']").parent().parent().append("<span id='checkspan_button' class='checkspan checkspan_unchecked'>&nbsp;</span>");
```

Also you can add a space instead of a &nbsp

```
$("[id$='somelement_detection']").parent().parent().append("<span id='checkspan_button' class='checkspan checkspan_unchecked'> </span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use this:

```
$("<span/>",{
   id: "checkspan_button",
   class: "checkspan checkspan_unchecked",
   html: "&nbsp;"
}).appendTo($("[id$='somelement_detection']").parent().parent())
```